# Как вычислять корень без переполнения?

Tags: python

у меня в программе **на питоне** необходимо считать корни больших чисел, точнее, выражений типа `n - int(n**0.5)**2`. Однако уже при вычислении выражения `2**105 - int((2**105)**0.5)**2` мне выдаёт отрицательный результат, несмотря на то, что `int()` округляет только в нижнюю сторону.

Можно ли каким-то хитрым путём избежать этого переполнения?

Comment: вы показали два абсолютно разных выражения, даже если притвориться, что `^` и `**` - одинаковые операции. так с каким из них проблемы ?

Comment: Это одинаковые выражения, просто во втором n = 2^105

Comment: `2^105 == 107`.  Это вы хотели?

Comment: считает вроде
>>> z = x**105 - int(x**(105/2))
>>> z
40564819207303334478842830046259
>>> x
2
>>> z = x**305 - int(x**(305/2))
>>> z
65185151242703554760590262029100101153646988589236227844794589869104267882625876274796560384
Python 3.11.5 (main, Aug 31 2023, 07:57:41) [GCC] on linux

Comment: А для чего вы считаете это выражение, какая основная задача?

Comment: А что ты ожидаешь в результате? ``2**105`` минус ``((2**105)/2)**2`` и будет отрицательный результат. Второе число примерно в 10е+31 больше первого.

Comment: @Эникейщик у меня int((2**105)/2), а int() округляет в нижниюю сторону

Comment: @БорисюкІван в данном случае округление вообще ни на что не влияет.

Comment: (2 ** 105)/2 это 2 ** 104. там нечего округлять. И если бы даже было, то на величине числа это никак не скажется.

Comment: @Эникейщик я ошибся, у меня корень из 2**105

Answer (score 5):

В стандартной библиотеке есть функция `isqrt`, для целочисленных корней:

```
import math

n = 2**105
print(n - math.isqrt(n)**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы путаете 2 различных операнда, `^` и `**`. Операнд `^` в Питоне это не возведение в степень (как в некоторых других языках), а `побитовое XOR` (Exclusive OR, исключительное ИЛИ).

Ваше выражение

```
2^105 - int(2^(105/2))
```

выдает после замены `^` на `**`, т.е. на

```
2**105 - int(2**(105/2))`
```

положительный результат `40564819207303334478842830046259`.

Comment: я ошибся, у меня было int((2**105)**0.5)